# Display of online users on the system

Tags: sql-server

I don't know exactly where I'm wrong, but I need a list of all the workers who are currently at work (for the current day), this is my sql query:

```
SELECT
    zp.ID, 
    zp.USER_ID, 
    zp.Arrive, 
    zp.Deppart, 
    zp.DATUM
FROM time_recording as zp 
INNER JOIN personal AS a on zp.USER_ID, = zp.USER_ID, 
WHERE zp.Arrive IS NOT NULL 
AND zp.Deppart IS NULL 
AND zp.DATUM = convert(date, getdate())
ORDER BY zp.ID DESC
```

this is what the data looks like with my query:
[image]

For me the question is, how can I correct my query so that I only get the last Arrive time for the current day for each user?
In this case to get only these values:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this below script using ROW_NUMBER as below-

```
SELECT * FROM 
(
    SELECT zp.ID, zp.USER_ID, zp.Arrive, zp.Deppart, zp.DATUM,
    ROW_NMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY zp.User_id ORDER BY zp.Arrive DESC) RN
    FROM time_recording as zp 
    INNER JOIN personal AS a 
    on zp.USER_ID = zp.USER_ID
    -- You need to adjust above join relation as both goes to same table
    -- In addition, as you are selecting nothing from table personal, you can drop the total JOIN part
    WHERE zp.Arrive IS NOT NULL 
    AND zp.Deppart IS NULL 
    AND zp.DATUM = convert(date, getdate())
)A
WHERE RN =1
```

Comment: You are most welcome @lasta. Nice to see that it helped :)

Answer (score 0):

you can try this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
   USER_ID,
   LAR.LastArrive
   FROM time_recording as tr
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT 
       MAX(Arrive) as LastArrive 
    FROM time_recording as ta
    WHERE
      tr.USER_ID = ta.USER_ID AND
      ta.Arrive IS NOT NULL
) as LAR
```